# What does it mean to retire as a member of an NFL team?

Tags: nfl

Tonight I saw [an article](https://www.packers.com/news/fb-john-kuhn-retires-as-a-packer) on the Green Bay Packers' official website saying that longtime fan-favorite fullback John Kuhn would be retiring as a Packer. It's not clear to me what that means.

John Kuhn did not play in the last NFL season and prior to that played a couple of years with the New Orleans Saints. The last team he played for was not the Packers. Nor does the article mention anything about him signing a 1-day contact with the team which I understand is something that happens occasionally. So what does it mean when the official team website says that he will be "retiring as a Packer"?

Answer (score 5):

Lots of contract stuff happens in March.  I am uncertain if there are any restrictions on signing free agents at the moment.

However, I would assume you can read this announcement that he intends to sign a 1-day contract.

There is one [article](https://www.12up.com/posts/6313209-former-packers-fan-favorite-john-kuhn-announces-retirement-from-football) that reports such a contract is planned, but it doesn't list the source for that information.

> Fullback ​John Kuhn announced that he will sign a one day contract and
>   retire as a Packer.